# Is there a way to add a cache buster to the RenderFormScripts Html helper function?

Tags: sitecore-forms, bundling, html-caching

In our `outerlayout.cshtml` file we have the following code:

```
@Html.RenderFormScripts()
```

which seems to loop round the JS files, that have been *attached* to the Sitecore form:

[image]

and create script tags for each of them in the finally outputted HTML.

Does anyone know of a way where we can add a cache buster to this functionality so that we don't have to remember to manually update the attached JS file references every time one of the source JS files changes ?

We have other areas, of the site, where JS files have cache busting on them by having a buildNumber parameter, which is incremented every time the source code is deployed to PROD, and then injecting this parameter into the script tag but it seems like we need to customise what the RenderFormScripts function does

Comment: Please include the version of your Sitecore instance to provide further context

Comment: You could add a redirect on a specific file from your-file.js to your-file.js?v=formatteddatetime. You would probably need to add it in code to grab the datetime, you could then control the frequency of the cache busting depending on the amount of detail you put in string (i.e. minute, hour, day, month etc)

Comment: @JuliusA, sorry forgot that bit. It's Sitecore 9.2

Comment: @DeanOBrien we already have a way of adding the cache buster (based on build number) and we use it in other areas of the code. I was hoping there was a way we could combine it with the RenderFormScripts function (which seems to be clever enough to only include the JS files IF there is a form on the page) but it looks like we will just have to try and replace that call with custom code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `IncludeFiles` processor of `forms.renderForm` pipeline and add custom parameter for all the scripts (or styles). Class below adds `DateTime.Now.Ticks` to scripts only. You can use your own logic there to include desired cache buster:

```
public class IncludeFiles : Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Pipelines.RenderForm.IncludeFiles
{
    protected override void IncludePath(HttpContextBase httpContext, string filePath, bool script)
    {
        var filePathWithCacheInfo = script ? $"{filePath}?{DateTime.Now.Ticks}" : filePath;
        base.IncludePath(httpContext, filePathWithCacheInfo, script);
    }
}
```

Remember to register your class with patch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <forms.renderForm>
                <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Pipelines.RenderForm.IncludeFiles, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc">
                    <patch:attribute name="type">MyAssembly.MyNamespace.IncludeFiles, MyAssembly</patch:attribute>
                </processor>
            </forms.renderForm>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome. Whilst I knew custom processors existed I had no idea where to even look for the processors that handle form scripts